# Why option menu items squeezed if I use support library 26?

Tags: android, android-support-library

The option menu items had the size they supposed to have with support library 25 but when I use 26.0.0, they all get squeezed.

menu item xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/people"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_addfriends_newsfeed"
        android:title=""
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

onCreateOptionsMenu in AppCompatActivity

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.newsfeed, menu);
    return true;
}
```

toolbar layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:theme="@style/ToolbarColoredBackArrow"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

[image: 25]

[image: 26.0.0]

Comment: what do you mean by "they all get squeezed." can you share screenshot and snippet of code

Comment: I added the screenshots.

Comment: Where do you have menu items drawables ?

Comment: Close voters are on crack.

Comment: Ok, that must be the reason. I thought the project already have drawables for all screen sizes. I'll change that and see if it fixes.

Comment: No, it didn't fix. I generated icons with Android Asset Studio and used them but the problem is still there

Comment: sorry, actually it fixed the problem. I just need to clean up the project and compile again.

Answer (score 3):

The project didn't have icons for different screen sizes. So, I generated icons with [Android Asset Studio](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/) for different screen sizes. I chose "Action bar/tab icon generator" in Android Asset Studio when I did. I add those icons into the project. I cleaned up the project and compiled it. It's finally fixed.