# Toolbar menu items squeezed after switching to support library 26 and AppBarActivity to AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-support-library, android-toolbar, android-support-design

Yesterday I switched to new support library 26 and I also had to change the deprecated AppBarActivity to AppCompatActivity since this is not existing anymore.

I'm experiencing the same problem as described in the link below but "clean" or "rebuild" does not fix the issue.
[Why option menu items squeezed if I use support library 26?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45429163/why-option-menu-items-squeezed-if-i-use-support-library-26)

I'm having all my icons in hdpi and xhdpi. Some also in mdpi and ldpi...

So why do my toolbar icons get squeezed?

Here is the code I use in all my layouts which worked with all previous support libraries (and I'm always using the most recent versions!):

```
   <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/myAppBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"


    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

All my icons are defined as attr so that I'm able to provide a light and a dark version.

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/action_logbook"
        android:icon="?attr/icon_book"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/logbook"
        yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
```

This is the attr in icons.xml

```
<attr name="icon_book" format="reference"/>
```

This is the style which provides the actual icon:

```
  <style name="MyBaseThemeLight" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="icon_book">@drawable/icon_book_white</item>
</style>
```

Here is a screenshot from before support version 26.0.0:
[image]

and this is after upgrade:
[image]

UPDATE:
It is working when I put an ImageView directly in Toolbar:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/myAppBar"
    style="@style/myAppBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="?attr/bt_expenses" />


    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

[image]

UDATE 2:
For me the code change in version 26 of ActionMenuItemView seems to be the problem since it does not resize the icons to keep width and high equal:

See:
`public void setIcon(Drawable icon)`
...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this thread on the Android issue tracker where I explain the bug: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64207386. I've also recompiled the library to fix the issue. Attached here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64207386#comment19.

EDIT: The issue is fixed on 26.0.2

Comment: Good to see that this issue is still not resolved in 26.0.1. Nice job Google!

Comment: @stefan I've recompile the appcompat-v7 library and fixed the issue. I've attached the AAR file here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64207386#comment19

Comment: I've seen that but I will wait until it is fixed officially. I don't need anything from new support library. I just wanted to stay up to date which is always a bad thing when working with Android/Google. 

Whatever, you have done a nice job!  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The workaround seems to use the Image Asset Studio from Android Studio to generate icon resources again. I didn't use that tool before and put the icon image manually in different resolution folders. it seems that com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0 changed the image resolution, my old hdpi icon was 72x72, the generated icon for hdpi is now 48x48.

Comment: I don't think this is a "workaround", I think it's the solution. This was happening for me too and it's because my images were too big to begin with. This brought my attention to it and now my images are correctly sized.

Comment: For me this is a bug in sdk, you just have to just check the code of ActionMenuItemView  see setIcon(). What is the reason to resize icons inappropriately? It's ok to resize them if they are to big but both sides should keep the same size! I switched back to previous version since all my images have exatly the size as described in documentation: hdpi =72px xhdpi 96px

Comment: Android team is already aware of this issue. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64207386 Star this on issue tracker

Answer (score 1):

These two action bars differ. Minimum height is set from the attributes, but both have a height value set to **wrap_content**.

The first bar consists a second line with km, which extends height of the App Bar by *wrapping* both textviews. Icons on the second one are shrinked, because they probably have attributes also set to wrap_content.

Would be better if you showed both App Bars that have the same design and comparison after changing to AppCompatActivity.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand your answer completely. What do you mean with "both App Bars"? I just have one. I also can't imagine that this is  the problem since I have the same behavior in "Activities" that don't have a "Subtitle"

Comment: Just updated my pictures so that they come from the same state (however, this makes no difference)

Comment: @stefan, can you try replacing gas station drawable with vector drawable?
[link](https://material.io/icons/#ic_local_gas_station) and check if it scales correctly? Also use [link](http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/) for converting svg to Android drawable. Images on the first screen, they are bigger than text and dots, on the second one all of these are equal.

Comment: I can try. However, this would require me to replace a lot of icons in my quite large application and is actually not a solution...

Comment: Maybe you can add vertical padding to title?

Comment: How to set it just for the title?

Comment: You can add margin to title in android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar:
`<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        app:titleMarginTop="30dp"`

Comment: Nope. This just moves the title down. The icons are still centered vertically and have the size of the text... Please check also my update. When I put a ImageView in Toolbar the icon is correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150935/discussion-between-maciej-and-stefan).